# Laravel 5 error when composer update

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider' not found
```

how to solve this error?

I am new for laravel framework

Comment: Look at this please (both answers) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034238/via-laravel-installer-method it might help you solving your issue

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://github.com/cachethq/Cachet/issues/694)  run following,

```
composer install --no-dev --no-scripts
composer install --no-dev -o
```

Comment: same issue, nothing happen

Comment: try 'composer dump-autoload' first and then try again please.

Comment: sorry, same issue no changes

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

- Delete your /vendor folder
- Delete composer.lock
- Run `composer install`

Make sure your composer.json file has `"laravel/framework": "5.1.*"`

Comment: `[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                      
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(D:\PHP\Code\rfidb\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\P
  HP\Code\rfidb\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17                                                                                         
  ` Will lose autoload.php

Answer (score 3):

- Delete your /vendor folder
- Delete composer.lock
- Run these commands

  1. composer install --no-dev --no-scripts
  2. composer install --no-dev -o
  3. composer install

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your `composer.json` file to use 5.1.* instead of 5.0.*

```
...

"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
},

...
```

Then run: `composer update` again.

Comment: @Sipon - I read somewhere that it's not wise to the wildcard * symbols in composer..

Comment: @Phorce - It depends on your update routine. Either way, you need to be aware of the target version when you upgrade, and not knowing what is included within the update process is going to cause more problems than using a wildcard. Although, using an exact version number could potentially save you some headaches, especially when a minor version upgrade requires manual intervention.

Comment: This worked for me - I was getting errors after composer update and using October CMS. Page now renders correctly. Not too worried about a production ready site - just playing around. Very time consuming trying to work out why the site suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

It may due to the problem with your php version. Verify that your php version > 5.5.9

```
php -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below command

```
composer self-update --rollback
```

close your ide and reopen it again.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should rolling back to an older version of Composer (not of any package you are using) resolve the problem? How does this related to any IDE?