# Laravel Installer method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

Normally I do install Laravel 5.1 by following this command regarding to documentation:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

It works fine.

But I read in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation) under "Via Laravel Installer" also it is possible to install **via Laravel Installer**, which is much faster than installing via Composer:

```
laravel new blog
```

But to use this method I need to run following command once:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

When I do run it I get following errors many times

> Deprecation Notice: Composer\Package\Version\VersionParser::parseLinks
>   is deprecated. Use \Composer\Package\Loader\ArrayLoader::parseLinks()
>   instead in
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionParser.php:226

after many line of same error `./composer.json has been updated` appears and it continues with the same line of errors, it ends with following

> Loading composer repositories with package information 
>  Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) 
>  Nothing to install or update 
>   Generating autoload files

What is wrong with it? Any idea or solution.

My environment: Windows 10, GitBash and cmder console.

Update of composer, I did ran `composer self-update` also

Snapshot of console
[image]

---

**EDIT:** 
Note, I can confirm after solving the issue that the installation via Laravel Installer method is faster than composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Composer Assets Plugin you've installed locally is using a deprecated method of Composer. The plugin is already fixed, so run `composer global update` to get the latest versions with the bug fix. After it, you should be able to run the command succesfully.

If this doesn't work (as you might get the same error running the previous command), try removing the global vendor directory. When running any global Composer command, it outputs something like "Changed current directory to XXX". Remove the `XXX/vendor` directory and then try running the command.

Comment: Ok when I run `composer global update` it come with the same error lines as in the question, what btw before I asked the question I did `composer self-update` also.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ I've updated my answer with an easier solution than uninstalling & installing Composer (but it has the same effect).

Comment: I have added my version of answer as addition to your answer in case any get stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @WouterJ answer.

Worst case if the steps provided by @WouterJ did not work, you could manage to uninstall and reinstall composer for windows.

When done, run `composer global update` to be sure to get latest updates, if there was.

Then run `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"` and it should works.

Remember to update your windows environment path `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`