# Composer error when running composer install

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to setup a new laravel project but composer is throwing a weird error.Mine is a `Windows 8` machine
THis is the stack trace

```
     composer diagnose -vvv
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (C:\wamp\www\knowShare): git describe --exact-match --tags
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (C:\wamp\www\knowShare): git describe --exact-match --tags



  [ErrorException]
  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty



Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Pipes/WindowsPipes.php:55
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at n/a:n/a
 fopen() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Pipes/WindowsPipes.php:55
 Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\WindowsPipes->__construct() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Pipes/WindowsPipes.php:172
 Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\WindowsPipes::create() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:1264
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->getDescriptors() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:273
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->start() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:208
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:62
 Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionGuesser.php:84
 Composer\Package\Version\VersionGuesser->guessGitVersion() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionGuesser.php:65
 Composer\Package\Version\VersionGuesser->guessVersion() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Loader/RootPackageLoader.php:68
 Composer\Package\Loader\RootPackageLoader->load() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Factory.php:270
 Composer\Factory->createComposer() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Factory.php:490
 Composer\Factory::create() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:225
 Composer\Console\Application->getComposer() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/Command.php:53
 Composer\Command\Command->getComposer() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/DiagnoseCommand.php:59
 Composer\Command\DiagnoseCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:147
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:82
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:25


diagnose
```

`php -r "var_dump(tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'sf_proc_stdout'));"`

This outputs `bool false`

I referred and tried the solutions here related to `sys_temp_dir` but did not fix the issue https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3835

What else can cause it,not sure by the stack trace.Any inputs would be helpful

Comment: Try this. I think it solves the problem. delete vendor folder completely. Then run `composer install`

Comment: no actually its a fresh install ..I am running `composer install` to get the vendor folder itself,I dont have it yet. @Ali

Comment: Looks like you already have it, becuz you have an error in WindowsPipes class on line 55

Comment: No i did not,but I resolved it by reinstalling it via admin.Not sure why it threw that error a first .Probably some permission issue which I did not understand

Comment: @Ali Its not resolved,I just checked it back,only the front end part worked but the backend seems to be stuck due to this error. I have tried updating the path for `sys_temp_dir` and also added composer in the path variable,still no luck. I am windows 8,just to update  if that might cause an issue.

Comment: try to update your composer and look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034238/via-laravel-installer-method not sure if that will help but worth try.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ I am using the latest freshly installed composer package,and also do not get this message anywhere.I don't think updating would fix.I will try it still,thank you for the update

Comment: @KillABug let me know I will be clever to know, thx

Comment: Also I have tried reinstalling and I am using a project checked out of git,so ideally  I should be running by doing `composer install` (This works on other machines fine)

Comment: In my case, to resolve a similar issue, I had completely removed the composer from the system and reinstalled it from the official site.