# Cannot Install Laravel 5.1 via composer

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.1

Start from tommorow, I don't know why I can't install the laravel 5.1 via composer create project.
Here is the error.
[image: Composer create project Laravel 5.1 Error]

At first I thought there is a problem with the composer, but when I tried to install Laravel 5.2, it's successfully created.

**Update:**
After I run the composer create-project, the vendor folder is not created.

Please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: That big block of yellow at the top looks like the problem - major permissions issues in your home directory. Did you previously run composer as root, perhaps?

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034238/via-laravel-installer-method it is windows but maybe some of it can be reused

Comment: @ceejayoz I've tried to run as root or as local user, and it's same.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I think that is different issue, he can install with composer create-project but he can't use the laravel installer. For me, I can install with laravel installer but it install the latest version (5.2). what I need is 5.1.

Comment: @Praditha thx for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been running in to this issue lately when creating new instances of my Laravel 5.1 projects.

From what I can piece together it is causing an issue when running the `php artisan clear-compiled` command as past of the install script.

To get around this I have been running my initial install with the `--no-scripts` option.

It looks like this is available when [creating a projec](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project)t too, so try running the below when installing Laravel 5.1 initially:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*" --no-scripts`

Comment: Yes great, it's working,. but one more question, is there anything miss if run create-project with --no-scripts argument,.?

Comment: It skips running `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize`, but you can run these afterwards. But the next time you run `composer update` it will run those commands anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Please run

```
composer update --prefer-dist
```

As per the comment and viewing the yellow message in the screen,Please try

```
sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's still not working, still get same error. And also the vendor folder is not created after I run the composer create-project.

Comment: try with `sudo` or `root user`

Comment: try `sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"`

Comment: Give write acess to cache directory of composer.

Comment: Yes already, and it's still get same result :(   I don't know, I think there is no problem with the composer, because I've tried to install for the laravel 5.2 and it's ok, there is no any problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a composer problem. Install `laravel` with:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"
```

Now, in your `composer.json` installed, remove this:

```
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
```

So, in your terminal update composer with this:

```
composer update --prefer-dist
```

This work for me.

Comment: Yes it works, but I prefer to choose @james answer, it more simple. Thanks any way